# Auto starting apps in LXDE doesn't work

Tags: lxde, pitft, startx

I'm trying to build a "kiosk" app for my Raspberry Pi 2 which has an Adafruit PiTFT connected to it (using their image, which is just the standard Debian Jessie, but with framebuffer stuff added to work with the PiTFT). But no matter what I do, I can't get any app (epiphany or otherwise) to run at startup. I've tried the following:

- Creating an `autostart` file in `/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart` (as well as `/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE/autostart`)
- Creating a `.xinitrc` file in `~/`
- Creating an `autostart` file in `/home/pi/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart` (and `/home/pi/.config/lxsession/LXDE/autostart`)
- Using absolute paths (e.g. `/usr/bin/lxterminal`)

But no matter what I do, nothing seems to run. I've added `@lxterminal`, a command I know I can run manually from within LXDE, plus I tried my `epiphany` command (which I can run manually), but upon doing a `sudo reboot` to restart (which auto-logs me in to LXDE), I get nothing but the standard ol' desktop.

Any suggestions?